# Update Data Extension with keyword in Mobile Connect Text response

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I was trying to trigger a specific MobileConnect text response keyword which should update a Data extension. When I add some ampscript to the outbound response, I get an error saying "There was an error processing your message".

Any ideas?

```
%%[ 
Var @message
if (Uppercase(MSG(0).VERB) == "LATER") then 
Set @message = "Thank you"
InsertData('Mobile_Response', 'MobileNumber', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'Keyword', "LATER", 'Response', MSG(0).NOUNS)
else 
Set @message = "Sorry" 
endif
]%% 

%%=v(@message)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an outbound message type or text response? You should use a "Text Response" message type so your ampscript can analyze the sms response. I think the issue might be that the term your looking for "LATER" isn't a verb. Also you should try using indexof in front of your IF to evaluate the whole message response. Try the following:

```
%%[ 
Var @message
if indexof(Uppercase(MSG(0).NOUNS) == "LATER") then 
Set @message = "Thank you"
InsertData('Mobile_Response', 'MobileNumber', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'Keyword', "LATER", 'Response', MSG(0).NOUNS)
else 
Set @message = "Sorry" 
endif
]%% 

%%=v(@message)=%%
```

Comment: Hi Nate,

We are Using Journey builder to send an “Outbound - Interaction” and using a “Text Response ” to collect the reply and adding it to the data extension. We tried your ampscript code but sadly without any luck. Still receiving “There was an error processing your message” after I replied with “LATER”. It might not be an ampscript problem, because even with a simple function (like setting the message variable) we get this error.

Comment: I'd try `SET @response = InsertData('Mobile_Response', 'MobileNumber', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'Keyword', "LATER", 'Response', MSG(0).NOUNS)`

Answer (score 0):

I want to make sure I understand.  You are using a Text Response message and just trying to evaluate the text sent to you and make a decision off what it is.

Are you using a text response message or the default keyword functionality?

Because if it isn't the keyword setup on the text response then you won't ever hit the alternative on the if statement.